# Is it possible to get a Table of contents in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

Is it possible to get a Table of contents in Notepad++

or if not, is there any text editor that is fast and can provide table of content feature. I am trying to avoid Windows Word which is way too slow for a 200 page document.

Answer (score 3):

To build an outline, a list of active links to the headers in NotePad++. You can markup your headers anyhow, search for that markup and select 'Find All in Current Document'. Like this

[image: Markdown headers regex example]

If you need the text of your TOC, actual headers, you can use Mark tab in the Search panel to bookmark all your headers, then go Menu\Search\Bookmark\Copy Bookmarked Lines. Like this

[image: Copy Bookmarked Lines menu item]

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom **[Function List](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/function-list/)** for it, although you will have no hierarchy (except maybe one with class searches).

A plugin does not exist yet, but certainly a library for it exist already and can be used to quickly make one.

Comment: in this link there is discussion/tips to use the function list to show a TOC based in MARKDOWN tags. https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/18458/display-markdown-outline-view-through-functionlist/9

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "table of contents" for plain txt files. For plain txt files only can be built the list of first sentences (or words) from each paragraph. SynWrite editor can be configured in such way (it has configurable txt lexer).

Answer (score 0):

The Amaya html editor, free from http://w3c.org/Amaya, easily creates a table of contents from the heading (h1 - h4) tagged items.  (But Amaya appears a buggy mess, at least on Mac OS X.)